# Form validation - Multiple responses in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, warnings, response, ng-bind

How can I make the app serve multiple responses at once. I have made a form based app and 3 fields are mandatory. However if you do not fill any of them, the app still throws a single warning message. If we fill in that field, we get another warning message. Is there a way to see all of them at once?

The response is stored in warnMessage

```
$scope.saveData = function(svcData) {
    GenericServiceSvc.callService(svcData).then(
      /**
       * @param {String} response - Response from the webservice.
       * @param {Object} response.resultCode - OK = file uploaded
       */
      function(response) {

        if(response=='OK') {
          $scope.uploaded=true;
          $scope.file=null;
          $scope.docType='';
        }
        else {

          $scope.warning=true;
          $scope.warnMessage = response;
        }
      },
      function () {
        $scope.warning=true;
        $scope.warnMessage = "Service failure";
      }
    );
  };
```

This is the bit in html

```
<div class="col-xs-10 alert alert-warning fade in" ng-bind="warnMessage" ng-show="warning" ></div>
```

So what I basically want to see is:

Fill in Field1
Fill in Field2
Fill in Field3

Instead of only one, even though 3 of them haven't been filled in.

Comment: You'll need to set `$scope.warnMessage` to an array of error messages instead of a single string. Then, in your template, use `ng-repeat` to create a warning for each of the error messages.

Comment: Why don't you validate required fields at client-side, using native angular support for that? This would make your problem go away (and would be simpler and faster).

Comment: AngularJS forms and controls provide validation services, so that the user can be notified of invalid input before submitting a form. This provides a better user experience than server-side validation alone because the user gets instant feedback on how to correct the error. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).